# use pd.read_csv on an opened file

Tags: python, pandas, file

My program is writing on an .csv file :

```
try :   
    out1 = open(chemin1, 'w')

    Logger.info('file opened')
except IOError :
    Logger.warning('IOError')
```

then I'm trying to use pd.read_csv on the same file :

```
df=pd.read_csv(chemin1, sep=';', decimal=',')
```

but an error occurs :

```
 File "parser.pyx", line 485, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4628)
   File "parser.pyx", line 607, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:6091)
 pandas.parser.CParserError: Passed header=0 but only 0 lines in file
```

However, if I close the file before I use `pd.read_csv()`, it is working.

So should I close the file, call `pd.read_csv()` and then re open the file or is there a more elegant solution ?

Comment: You should close the file before accessing using read_csv. There is no other way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out1 = open(chemin1, 'w')`, operation system will **lock** chemin1 in disk and prevent other to read or write something until you complish writing and **close** file. Otherwise, there will be conflicting. Just imagining that, two ones without knowing each other exsit write something to same file at same time, the content of the file will be chaotic.
And it's is allow that many processes read file at same time, likes, many people read same book, they get same content.

Comment: thank you for your aswer, 
so in my case it is mandatory to : 
-open file 
-write in my file
-close file
-pd.read_csv()
-re open the file  ?

Comment: yes . you are right. the open with 'w' or 'r',  you should notice.